# How to query Firestore and read value as javascript Number type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I save a Number to Firestore. I then try to read it from within a cloud function and store the value in a Javascript variable which should be of type Number.

```
const doc = await db.collection('lastBlock').doc('lastBlockNumber').get();
if (doc.exists) {
    lastBlockNumber = Number(doc.data());
}
```

I also tried:

```
if (doc.exists) {
    lastBlockNumber = doc.data() as unknown as Number;
}
```

But I either get NaN or [Object object] when trying to print the value of lastBlockNumber.

Here is a screenshot of my DB structure:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A document in Firestore is a set of fields. Calling `data()` on a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) gives you an object with those fields.

If you want to get a specific field, you can call `get(...)` on the snapshot. So:

```
lastBlockNumber = doc.get("lastBlockNumber") as Number;
```

Where `lastBlockNumber` is the name of the field you want to get. Check if the `as Number` cast is actually needed here, as Firestore may already return the value as the correct type.